# How to make a binomial logistic regression model with repeated measures in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have data on 10000 people and each person has been observed 100 times, 2 of the explanatory variables are qualitative. I have an idea of how to approach a linear regression model or binomial logistic regression model, but I have never dealt with repeated observations.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at `glmer` from the `lme4` package. It may be appropriate to model with your subjects as a random effects term, something like `glmer(outcome ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + (1|subject_id), data = df, family = binomial)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.